# jqGrid - Submit Grid ID In POST Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, jqgrid

I have multiple grids on a single page so my PHP needs to know which jqGrid POST data came from.  I thought I could easily use something such as:

```
jQuery('#grid1').jqGrid({
    ...
    postData:
    {
        grid: function() { return $(this).attr('id'); }
    },
    ...
});
```

POST certainly contains `grid` but the value is populated.  For testing I put...

`alert($(this).attr('id'));`

...elsewhere in my code and it displayed the grid name.  I'm not sure how/where to get the value into POST though.

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Well, I could simply statically assign the grid name to `postData`.  Duh.  But now I'm still curious how to dynamically retrieve the grid name to populate in `postData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added a new field to the POST which contains the "type" of data being submitted so my API knows what it is being handed.